# if else-if making code look ugly any cleaner solution?

Tags: python

I have around 20 functions (is_func1, is_fucn2, is_func3...) returning boolean

I assume there is only one function which returns true and I want that!

I am doing:

```
if is_func1(param1, param2):
    # I pass 1 to following
    abc(1) # I pass 1
    some_list.append(1)
elif is_func2(param1, param2):
    # I pass 2 to following
    abc(2) # I pass 1
    some_list.append(2)
...
.
.
elif is_func20(param1, param2):
...
```

Please note: param1 and param2 are different for each, abc and some_list take parameters depending on the function.

The code looks big and there is repetition in calling abc and some_list, I can pull this login in a function! but is there any other cleaner solution?

I can think of putting functions in a data structure and loop to call them.

Comment: What do the functions is_func look like internally?

Comment: Could you update with a little more realistic code?, for instance, you say in your note `param1` and `param2` are different, but you are showing the same. Is there a function like this `is_funcN( param3, param4, param5):`??

Comment: @Fletcher: Inside is a complex expression evaluating to a boolean

Comment: @Oscar: All function takes two parameters, which can be different for each.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
functionList = [is_func1, is_func2, ..., is_func20]
for index, func in enumerate(functionList):
    if(func(param1, param2)):
        abc(index+1)
        some_list.append(index+1)
        break
```

Comment: I think there would be a problem if the functions take different parameters.

Comment: @Oscar: True, but that would be a different question with a different answer

Comment: yeap, I didn't quite get the question in first place, it says: *Please note: param1 and param2 are different for each*  I added a comment on the OP

Comment: If the parameters are different, Adam's answer is probably best.

Comment: I posted a modification of your code which should work with differing parameters for each function.

Answer (score 2):

> I can think of putting functions in a data structure and loop to call them.

Yes, probably you should do that since your code needs to be refactored,
and a data driven design is a good choice.

An example similar to [BlueRaja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776125/if-else-if-making-code-look-ugly-any-cleaner-solution/2776214#2776214),

```
# arg1, arg2 and ret can have any values on each record
data = ((isfunc1, arg1, arg2, ret),
 (isfunc2, arg1, arg2, ret),
 (isfunc3, arg1, arg2, ret),
  ...)

for d in data:
    if d[0](d[1], d[2]):
        abc(d[3])
        some_list.append(d[3])
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

If each branch of your event dispatcher is in fact different, then there just isn't any way to get around writing the individual branch handlers, and there isn't any way to get around polling the different cases and choosing a branch.

Comment: I'm not sure to what extent he has replaced code with dummy names but it looks like he could be much more DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
value = 1 if is_func1(param1, param2) else \
        2 if is_func2(param1x, param2x) else \
        ... else \
        20 if is_func20(param1z, param2z) else 0

abc(value)
some_list.append(value)
```

Bear in mind that this statement was cobbled together using various websites as a reference for Python syntax, so please don't shoot me if it doesn't compile.

The basic gist is to produce a single value that corresponds to the function called (1 for `is_func1`, 2 for `is_func2`, etc.) then use that value in the `abc` and `some_list.append` functions. Going on what I was able to read about Python boolean expression evaluation, this should properly short-circuit the evaluation so that the functions stop being called as soon as one evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a good case to apply [Chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

I know how to give the example with objects, not functions, so I'll do that:

```
class HandleWithFunc1
   def __init__(self, otherHandler):
      self.otherHandler = otherHandler

   def Handle(param1, param2):
     if ( should I handle with func1? ):
          #Handle with func1
          return
     if otherHandler == None:
        raise "Nobody handled the call!"

     otherHandler.Handle(param1, param2)

class HandleWithFunc2:
   def __init__(self, otherHandler):
      self.otherHandler = otherHandler

   def Handle(param1, param2):
     if ( should I handle with func1? ):
          #Handle with func1
          return
     if otherHandler == None:
        raise "Nobody handled the call!"

     otherHandler.Handle(param1, param2)
```

So you create all your classes like a chain:

```
handle = HandleWithFunc1(HandleWithFunc2())
```

then:

```
handle.Handle(param1, param2)
```

This code is prone to refactoring, here only to illustrate the usage

Comment: And then the next poor schmuck gets to search all over the application for all the various handlers, and gets to figure out for himself the order in which their guards are tested.

Sometimes, you are better off with the straightforward, ugly solution.

Comment: Do they need an order? That's not stated in the question

Answer (score 1):

I modified BlueRaja answer for different parameters...

```
function_list = {is_func01: (pa1, pa2, ...),
                 is_func02: (pa1, pa2, pa3, ...), 
                 ....
                 is_func20: (pa1, ...)}

for func, pa_list in function_list.items:
    if(func(*pa_list)):
        abc(pa_list_dependent_parameters)
        some_list.append(pa_list_dependent_parameters)
        break
```

I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used python before, but can you refer to functions by a variable?

If so, you can create an enum with entries representing each function, test all the functions in a loop, and set a variable to the 'true' function's enum.

Then you can do a switch statement on the enum.

Still, that won't 'clean up' the code much: when you have n options and need to drive down to the correct one, you'll need n blocks of code to handle it.

Comment: You don't really gain anything by writing a linear search for the appropriate dispatch index, followed by a switch() on the dispatch index.

This is one of those where you're probably better off just biting the bullet.

Comment: Agree, but it could be better than having all the function calls in the if/else tree.

Comment: Functions are first class in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it would be cleaner, but I think is's quite interesting solution.

First of all you should define new function, let it be `semi_func`, which will call `abc` and `some_list.append` do make code DRY.

Then set new variable to act as a binary result of all boolean functions, so the is_func1 is 20th bit of it, is_func2 is 19th and so on.
32 bits of integer type should be enough to handle all 20 results.

While setting value to this result variable you should use shift left to add new functions:

```
result = is_func1(param1, param2) << 1
result = (result | is_func2(param1, param2)) << 1
...
result = (result | is_func20(param1, param2))
```

For ease access define new constants like

```
IS_FUNC20_TRUE = 1
IS_FUNC19_TRUE = 2
IS_FUNC18_TRUE = 4
... values should be powers of 2
```

And in the end use switch/sase statement to call `semi_func`.

Answer (score -3):

I know I will be modded down for being offtopic, but still. If you find anything that can be done with standard control constructs off-putting, then you need to use a different language, such as Common Lisp, which allows for macros, in effect makes it possible to create your own control constructs. (Having recently discovered anaphoric macros, I just have to recommend this.)

This specific case would be a perfect example where a macro would help, but only assuming you are doing it at multiple places in your code, otherwise it's probably not worth improving at all. And in fact, Common Lisp already has a macro like that, it's called **cond**.

Anyway, in Python, I think you should go along with a list of functions and a loop.

Comment: -1; not for off-topic - the problem is not standard controls, but the repetition of code.  I would -1 again for suggesting macros if I could.

Comment: @BlueRaja... let me do it, but mine was for posting an answer when this could be a perfect comment in the original post.

Comment: BlueRaja - do you know Common Lisp? You contradict yourself. Almost any repetition of code can be solved easily by using a suitable macro, and it's not a bad thing. If you don't know what I mean, read the chapter 3 of excellent book Practical Common Lisp.